# Installing laravel on server

Tags: laravel

I am installing laravel on server via putty. I linked public with public_html. Files were located inside laravel folder above public_html. After installation its showing "Internal Server Error"

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: There are many changes for `Internal Server Error` describe with more details ?

Comment: When I access server after installation of Laravel, without any modification to index.php and any other file. Its showing this error.

Comment: Is your server using cPanel or Plesk? Do you have SSH access? Is the domain pointing to the public folder of your Laravel app or the root folder?

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: Its cpanel. I connected with Putty and installing via that. Showing error. Kindly check http://chandigarhtutors.com/

Comment: Not in logs yet.

Comment: @RossWilson its using cpanel, I connected with Putty. Domain point to public folder of laravel.

Comment: @NikleshRaut I installed laravel outside public_html inside laravel folder. No other settings were made. public folder is linked with public_html

Comment: To be fair, it sounds like it's going to be a permissions issue. Make sure the `index.php` file in the public folder has 644 permissions.

Comment: @RossWilson You are Genius! It works! Thanks

Comment: @user2783324 Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when using cPanel it will usually require your `index.php` to have the permissions 644 otherwise you'll get a 500 error.

You can change this in cPanel by doing the following:

1. Login to your cPanel (if not already there)
2. Click File Manager.
3. Click the name of the file for which you would like to change the
   permissions.
4. Select the Change Permissions link at the top right of the page.
5. Select the permissions you would like to set for the file

   - **Owner** - Read and write
   - **Group** - Read
   - **World** - Read
6. Click Change Permissions.

---

Alternatively, if you have ssh access you could run the following command on the server:

```
chmod 644 path/to/index.php
```

Comment: Also, I am new on laravel. Any suggestions for good stuff. Though I check here and there from google for documentation / study material.

Comment: Thanks for quickly responding  :)